# Add logo on each page.

Tags: graphics, watermark

I need to insert a logo on pdflatex supported format on the bottom right of each page.

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: yes. use \savebox and a footer

Answer (score 25):

You can use the package [`eso-pic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,lipsum}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{1cm}A small logo: \rule{2cm}{3cm}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The above gives:

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion! I always forget about `eso-pic`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I put a pdf rather than "A small logo: \rule{2cm}{3cm}"?

Comment: @Tanda as always: with includegraphics

Answer (score 24):

You can easily set headers and footers using the `fancyhdr` package. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{My Logo here!}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

Note that the `lipsum` package is just to get sample text, it's not part of the solution.

Comment: Same question as above.  How to I put a pdf rather than "My logo here!"?  Thanks!

Comment: `\rfoot{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{mylogo.pdf}}`

Answer (score 15):

Using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum} % used to create the lipsum text

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ([xshift=-1.2in,yshift=1.2in] current page.south east) % Adjust the position of the logo.
{\rule{2cm}{3cm}}; % logo goes here
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]