# In a multiple file LaTeX document, is there a way to tag each page with the file that generated it?

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2, file-lookup, currfile

I've got a LaTeX document that's build from many smaller files.  When I'm editing text or formulas I usually look for some characteristic text and do something like:

```
find -name "*.tex" > t
grep -n 'text of interest' `cat t` | tee v
vim -q v
```

I see that there's a [`currfile`](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile/currfile.pdf) package.  I'd like to know if there's a way that I could use the `\currfilename` command in that package to stamp the margin with the filename (and/or path), or perhaps even just to generate a footnote.

EDIT: I found a way to do this in a standalone example, and that's posted below as a self-answer, which I initially thought to be sufficient.  However, that answer used fancyhdr, and I'm using the classicthesis template which uses scrpage2, so a fancyhdr solution doesn't work.  I've been able to make updates to classicthesis.sty to show the filenames in the chapter and section headers using `\currfilepath`, but would really like this to be a page level footer (one that I'd eventually make conditional on the drafting flag).

This is the scrpage2 section from classicthesis that I'd like to modify:

```
% ********************************************************************
% headlines
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{automark}{scrpage2}
  \RequirePackage{scrpage2} % provides headers and footers (KOMA Script)
    \clearscrheadings
    \setheadsepline{0pt}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
    \lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}\headmark\hfil}}
    \rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\thepage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headfont}{\small}
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[2]{} % <--- ToDo
    % hack to get the content headlines right (thanks, Lorenzo!)
     \def\toc@heading{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\section*{\contentsname}}%nochapters
        {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
        \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}}
```

Comment: Are you adding the files using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)?

Comment: just a main .tex file that does various \input's and \include's of other .tex files.

Comment: While this does not answer your question you should really consider using the `--synctex` compile time option that is built into most of the editors. You simply right click on the output PDF and the actual source file that produced it opened.  This will save you a **lot** of time.

Comment: Looks like I have to use TexWorks instead of acrobat to view the pdf for this to work.  Thanks for the tip.  It would be nice to be able to invoke other editors though.  Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: ps.  had to use -synctex=1, not --synctex

Comment: No, don't know how to use Acrobat, but as you are writing the files, it is best to just stay within TeXWorks at least for revisions. Also, you need to use @<userid> when messaging, otherwise I might not have seen this.

Comment: My LaTeX environment (Windows) is the Sublime Text 2 editor with the [LaTeXTools package](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#forward-and-inverse-search) which allows a forward and inverse search with the SumatraPDF viewer.

Comment: Without the sublime editor installed, SumatraPDF automatically detected my vim installation.  Given how nicely that works, there's hardly any point to actually including a filename footnote in the document!  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perhaps poor form to answer my own question, but I found a mechanism for this in the following question:

[Add logo on each page.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/add-logo-on-each-page)

The following example shows how things fit together

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{currfile}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{\currfilepath}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\lipsum
\clearpage
\include{a/b/f1}
\include{a/b/f2}
\include{a/b/f3}
\include{a/b/f4}
\include{a/b/f5}
\include{a/b/f6}
\end{document}
```

where f1, f2, f3, ... all contain the following

```
\lipsum
\clearpage
```

As desired, I see `a/b/f1.tex`, `a/b/f2.tex` on all the `\include` generated pages (and the main .tex filename on the one that does the `\include`'s).

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question – it might be a valuable source for others! You should also consider accepting it, eventually (maybe after waiting a couple of days for other answers.)

Comment: With `currfile` there should not be a reason to use `\clearpage` at the end of `\include` file. `\include` adds a `\clearpage` before and after the file content anyway and `currfile` uses `filehook` to change the file names *after* the last page is written. Did you experienced that differently? I'm the author of `currfile` and `filehook` so I would like to know if there are any issues. Originally I had similar code in my `svn-multi` package which required such an explicit `\clearpage` to get the header and footer of the last pages correct.

Comment: You are right.  `\clearpage` is not required with any of the `\include`'d files.