# Put some text at a precise x, y position

Tags: boxes, text

I have a page which already has a very precise layout with many boxes: text, graphics (PNG), etc.

Without changing the current layout, and without changing anything that could impact the next pages, I'd like to add a textbox with a precise position, with something like:

```
\positiontextbox{3cm}{10cm}{Hello}    %  3 cm from left border of paper
                                      % 10 cm from top border of paper
```

This would be the LaTeX equivalent of HTML/CSS's `#mytextbox { position: fixed; left: 20px; top: 100px; }`.

**How to do this in LaTeX ?**

Comment: You can e.g use eso-pic. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7637/2388

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Ti*k*Z node `current page.north west`, it is possible to place some content precisely on a specified position relative to the upper left corner of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\positiontextbox}[4][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%    \draw[step=0.5,gray!80!white] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east); % For controlling
    \node[inner sep=10pt,right, fill=yellow,draw,line width=1pt,#1] at ($(current page.north west) + (#2,-#3)$) {#4};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]

\positiontextbox{3cm}{10cm}{Hello}

\positiontextbox[fill=green]{14cm}{5cm}{Hello World}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**The version with the requested circle** (The line wrapping is from a very useful hint from [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\positiontextbox}[4][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%    \draw[step=0.5,gray!80!white] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east); % For controlling
    \node[align=left,circle,inner sep=5pt,right, fill=white,draw,#1] at ($(current page.north west) + (#2,-#3)$) {#4};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]

\positiontextbox{3cm}{10cm}{Hello}

\positiontextbox[fill=green]{14cm}{5cm}{Hello\\ World}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer! I'm currently playing with it. Little additions: how to remove the border (I did it by removing `draw` is that the good way to do it?), have a solid white *circle* background instead?

Comment: @Basj: Yes, that's the way to do so. I just used the border to make the box more outstanding. With solid white circle background you mean that the box is a white circle actually?

Comment: I mean like this @ChristianHupfer: http://imgur.com/a/3qacx

Comment: @Basj: A white circle in the center of the rectangle box and the text in the middle of the circle?

Comment: In my screenshot, the blue background is external to the textbox, it's the background of the page. So the only thing that needs to be drawn is the plain solid white circle + the text inside.

Comment: @Basj: Try `\node[circle,inner sep=5pt,right, fill=white,#1] at ($(current page.north west) + (#2,-#3)$) {#4};` instead of the other posted `\node` command

Comment: @Basj: You're welcome. Happy TeXing