# Watermark or rubber stamp-type heading for draft number on the top of EVERY page of a book

Tags: book-design

I will be submitting my thesis to my committee soon.  I expect that my thesis will go through several drafts, and I will be posting these on a filesharing platform for my committee to view.

- I would like to print a rather large, bold "watermark"/"rubber stamp"
  heading, with text of my choosing, on the top of each page of my
  thesis, regardless of whether the page is a "normal" chapter text
  page or front matter, etc.
- I may also want to repeat this text at the
  bottom of every page as well, just to make it clear to the reader
  which draft version they are reading.
- I don't need to do programmatic version control or anything; I am just looking to stamp a heading on every page with text of my (manual) choosing.

How can I do this in LaTex?

Here is a MWE, followed by an image showing the kind of text I would like to put on the top *every* page.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title page}

\section*{Preliminary stuff}

\chapter{This is Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Chapter 2}
\lipsum[8-15]

\end{document}
```

[image: newExample]

Comment: You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic), as described here: [Add logo on each page.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7630/5764); [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using `TikZ` and `graphicx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38751/5764) It doesn't have to be a graphic. It could be anything, including text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place content in the `F`ore`G`round of *every* page using `\AddToShipoutPictureFG{<stuff>}` (the starred version `\AddToShipoutPicture*` will place it on the current page only; there is also a `B`ack`G`round equivalent). Placement macros like `\AtPageUpperLeft` and `\AtPageLowerLeft` help with positioning.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{% Add something to the ForeGround of every page
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-2em}{\hspace*{2em}%
      \scalebox{5}{\color{black!30}\bfseries DRAFT}%
    }%
  }%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{2em}{\hspace*{2em}%
      \scalebox{5}{\color{black!30}\bfseries DRAFT}%
    }%
  }%
}%


\begin{document}

\section*{Title page}

\section*{Preliminary stuff}

\chapter{This is Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Chapter 2}
\lipsum[8-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between background and foreground? Does background mean that document objects will be printed on top of the heading?

Comment: @Andrew: Correct. The sequence of printing the shipped out page is `BG`, then the page, then `FG`.